# Prefilled form, restrict form fields from editing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've created a pre-filled google form and want the the field which pre-filled needs to be restricted from editing?  Is it possible?  Options can be app script or any settings on form.

[image]

Here the trix where pre-filled forms are generated: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qe87YwW5cy8ZhXdXoqPrUH6t0HCGVpLOKgF14qM1bLI/edit#gid=0

Form link:https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1yubdtkNWDx8U2X8cRwJUO3WgrChVxuDCC5rw686sxgk/edit

Any insights are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think that in the current stage, your goal cannot be achieved using Google Forms. So, in this case, I think that it is required to use a workaround. In order to achieve your goal, how about using the custom HTML form as a workaround? By this, I think that your goal can be achieved. But, if this was not included in the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: On a tangent, why create a pre-filled ID field at all? Or, if the response value is important for later analysis, why not "hide" the question?

Comment: I tried hiding the question, it is not capturing the emp id in the response trip.

Comment: @Tanaike you mean to use web app using appscript?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `you mean to use web app using appscript?`, it's yes. You can see the official document at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web